# Problem with configure(HttpSecurity http) error: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying do one example [here link](https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-5-spring-security-5-hibernate-5-example) and i eliminated all possible errors, but stayed one:

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
```

In the end of stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.antMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:122)
    at com.windigital.config.WebSecurityConfig.configure(WebSecurityConfig.java:37)
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The problem in this antMatcher:

```
.antMatchers("/login**")
```

Please help me, and tell me about this configure() method or give me links. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have read this guide [securing-web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) and create htt like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
```

Comment: May I ask what does ".csrf().disable()" do? What happens if it is absent?

Comment: @KumarManish csrf enables functions of csrf - Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces authenticated users to submit a request to a Web application against which they are currently authenticated. CSRF attacks exploit the trust a Web application has in an authenticated user.